# A camera zoom issue with libGDX

Tags: camera, libgdx, zooming

Hey guys I'm working on a android game with libGDX, and I got a zoom problem here. It's basically a ski safari style 2D game, and I want to implement a zoom in/out effect as the height changing. Is that possible to work this out with OrthoGraphicCamera? Or shall I change the size of the objects in real time(because I still wanna keep the background in a fixed size)?

Comment: What about `Camera.zoom`?

Comment: Well I need to keep the background static so the Camera.zoom would not be a nice idea, and Angel Angel has shown me a preferable solution. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could have just set camera.zoom to 1, then draw your background, then change it to whatever value you want and draw the other objects.

Comment: Do you mean like batcher.start(); drawBackground();batcher.end();camera.zoom(scale);camera.update(); batcher.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);batcher.start();drawItems();batcher.end(); I've tried this but the background still zooms with other items :(

Comment: exactly like that, but with camera.zoom(1f);camera.update(); batcher.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); before rendering the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Camera.zoom` not solve your problem, you can use
batch unmodified to draw your backgroud, and use `batch.getProjectionMatrix().cpy().scale (yourScaleVariableX, yourScaleVariableY, 0);`
to simulate only the items that you want, varying varibles, not if you're looking hopefully help.

simple example:

variable Class

```
Matrix4 testMatrix;
float yourScaleVariableX;
float yourScaleVariableY;
```

example render method

.//

```
batch.begin();

yourBackground.draw...

batch.end();

batch.begin();

testMatrix = batch.getProjectionMatrix().cpy().scale (yourScaleVariable, yourScaleVariable, 0);

batch.setProjectionMatrix(testMatrix);

yourItem.draw..

batch.end();
```

I think it is more efficient, changing the matrix, which resize all objects.

I hope to explain well.

**Edit**

I did not realize when I wrote the answer, you can store save the original matrix, before editing it for later use, or use `batch.setProjectionMatrix (camera.combined);` to restore

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'm gonna work on it soon and hope this does work.

Comment: I've tried but I declared two batcher to handle this problem and it works fine now, does that bring any further problems? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cloud I do not understand very well the English sorry, but when you say you declare two batch, if what you do is what the example that I put really you're not declaring two bacth you are using the same but you are modifying, although it is preferable whenever possible to create all draw in a call to batch.begin batch.end I do not think that call two begin one after another affect too much,while excessive use is not made, I think.

Comment: @Cloud you could also try 1-batch.begin 2- draw.background, 3 -testMatrix = batch.getProjectionMatrix () 4-batch.setProjectionMatrix ...... (testMatrix); 5-yourItem.draw .. 6- batch.end. But not if this will give some kind of error changing the matrix within the batch begin but you can try it hope it will help.